# Sysprep is getting failed

Tags: windows, azure, sysprep

I tried to run sysprep in one windows vm hosted in azure, it failed. below error I can see in setuperr log. Could you please check what is the problem here?

```
2018-08-20 12:53:10, Error      [0x0f0060] SYSPRP ParseCommands:Found unsupported command line option '/generlize'
2018-08-20 12:53:10, Error      [0x0f00a4] SYSPRP WinMain: Unable to parse command-line arguments to sysprep; GLE = 0x0
2018-08-20 12:54:07, Error      [0x0f0043] SYSPRP WinMain:The sysprep dialog box returned FALSE
2018-08-20 12:54:24, Error      [0x0f0043] SYSPRP WinMain:The sysprep dialog box returned FALSE
2018-08-20 12:54:31, Error      [0x0f0043] SYSPRP WinMain:The sysprep dialog box returned FALSE
2018-08-20 12:54:39, Error      [0x0f0066] SYSPRP ParseCommands:No action flag was specified but sysprep is in quiet mode
2018-08-20 12:54:39, Error      [0x0f00a4] SYSPRP WinMain: Unable to parse command-line arguments to sysprep; GLE = 0x0
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error                 SYSPRP WSLicenseCleanUpState failed with hr=c0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'WSLicenseCleanUpState' from C:\Windows\System32\wsclient.dll; dwRet = 0xc0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteAction: Error in executing action; dwRet = 0xc0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteActionList: Error in execute actions; dwRet = 0xc0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Error in executing actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0xc0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0xc0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0xc0020017
2018-09-20 15:10:59, Error      [0x0f00a8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0xc0020017
```

Answer (score 1):

The first several lines are simply due to a typo in the flag name `/generlize`.

The `WSLicenseCleanUpState failed with hr=c0020017` can be caused when you've disabled the windows store service.

Your second error is probably due to the multiple attempts to run sysprep... look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929828 for the official kb, and https://www.wintips.org/fix-sysprep-fatal-error-dwret-31-machine-invalid-state-couldnt-update-recorded-state/ for a (hack?) workaround if that doesn't help.

Comment: I have started the windows store service and tried to sysprep again, but the below error


2018-09-20 15:45:44, Error      [0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet = 0x1f
2018-09-20 15:45:44, Error      [0x0f00ae] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup external providers; hr = 0x8007001f